# Bundle Config in MVC 5 is not rendering after hosting the application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are developing an application in MVC5 and using Visual studio 2017.
We have added all the common jquery and css files in bundle config but those are not rendering after the application is getting hosted in IIS. In the development phase, the application is working perfectly.

[image: BundleConfig.cs]

Referring the layout page.

[image: Layout.cshtml]

WebGrease is also added by default as a reference in the project.

[image: WebConfig]

Please help to complete the hosting.

Comment: Post your code not image of your code

Comment: show rendered HTML where the included scripts/css should be.  Also, check the browser dev console for error responses to requests to the bundles.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is likely due to you having a bundle configured like this:

```
new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
```

whilst at the same time having a `Content` folder in the project, that has a `css` subfolder.

Change the bundle name so that it doesn't clash with a real folder, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have created a css folder inside Content folder of project and kept a copy of all the css files listed. But no luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but to clarify, I am suggesting that you had a *physical folder* called `css` under the `Content` folder.  Your bundle name, `~/Content/css` clashes with this.  Change the name of the bundle (e.g. to `~/Content/appcss` or something.